# Sentencia SQL charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server

he creado una sentencia sql que recorre una cadena y genera columnas con datos.

**CODIGO:**

```
select p.FK_workitem,
         p.numero_sd, 
         p.PARRAFO,
         LTRIM(substring(p.PARRAFO, 0, CHARINDEX(':', p.PARRAFO))) Tipo,
         LTRIM(substring(p.PARRAFO, CHARINDEX('Fs.', p.PARRAFO)+3, (CHARINDEX('Nro.', p.PARRAFO) -3) - CHARINDEX('Fs.', p.PARRAFO))) Foja,
         LTRIM(substring(p.PARRAFO, CHARINDEX('Nro.', p.PARRAFO)+4, (CHARINDEX('Año', p.PARRAFO) -8) - CHARINDEX('Nro.', p.PARRAFO))) Número,
         LTRIM(substring(p.PARRAFO, CHARINDEX('Año', p.PARRAFO)+4,5 )) Año,
         LTRIM(substring(p.PARRAFO, CHARINDEX('Año', p.PARRAFO)+9,LEN(p.PARRAFO) )) Contenido
   from (select FK_workitem, numero_sd, [dbo].[FNC_GET_FILA_UNIDAS](FK_workitem,PK_id,numero_sd) as PARRAFO from RCD_tbl_gp_detalle where  linea like '%:%') p
```

tengo dos casos que se me presentan, ya que el index cambia. ejemplos

1. CASO 1: a Fs. 35933 Nro. 39021 del Año 2017 en favor de Itaú Corpbanca para garantizar al acreedor el cumplimiento de las obligaciones que contraiga actualmente o en el futuro
2. CASO 2: al día de hoy le afecta: una Hipoteca, inscrita a Fs. 744 N ° 698, correspondiente al año 2010, a favor del Banco del Estado de Chile.- DOY FE.-

La pregunta es:
como puedo generar sentencias dentro del chardindex. porque actualmente solo tengo un index. 'fs.'- 'Nro.'-'Año'
el otro caso o index que debe contener seria.

- Nro. y N
- Año y año

Gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En estos casos es dónde se extrañan las expresiones regulares en SQL Server, hay que decirlo, la búsqueda de patrones en el motor es sumamente limitada, lo único que podemos hacer es buscar un patrón o cadena inicial y un patrón o cadena posterior para poder recortar lo que tenemos entre estos. En definitiva es lo que ya estás haciendo, pero lo que te falta es la posibilidad de definir distintos criterios de recorte en función de dos casos que has definido.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una clausula `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END` y definir un patrón de búsqueda en la cadena que defina el comportamiento del recorte.

La idea sería algo así:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(PARRAFO, PATINDEX('% Año [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', PARRAFO) + 5, 4) AS 'AÑO',
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('% N ° [0-9]%,%', PARRAFO) > 0 THEN 
                    SUBSTRING(PARRAFO,
                              PATINDEX('% N ° [0-9]%,%', PARRAFO) + 5,
                              CHARINDEX(',', PARRAFO, PATINDEX('% N ° [0-9]%,%', PARRAFO)) - PATINDEX('% N ° [0-9]%,%', PARRAFO) - 5
                      )
             WHEN PATINDEX('% Nro. [0-9]%', PARRAFO) > 0 THEN 
                    SUBSTRING(PARRAFO,
                              PATINDEX('% Nro. [0-9]%', PARRAFO) + 6,
                              CHARINDEX(' del', PARRAFO, PATINDEX('% Nro. [0-9]%', PARRAFO)) - PATINDEX('% Nro. [0-9]%', PARRAFO) - 6
                      )
        ELSE NULL END AS 'NUMERO'


        FROM (SELECT 'a Fs. 35933 Nro. 39021 del Año 2017 en favor de Itaú Corpbanca para garantizar al acreedor el cumplimiento de las obligaciones que contraiga actualmente o en el futuro' AS PARRAFO
          UNION
          SELECT 'al día de hoy le afecta: una Hipoteca, inscrita a Fs. 744 N ° 698, correspondiente al año 2010, a favor del Banco del Estado de Chile.- DOY FE.-'
          ) T
```

Salida:

```
+---+------+--------+
| # | AÑO  | NUMERO |
+---+------+--------+
| 1 | 2017 | 39021  |
+---+------+--------+
| 2 | 2010 | 698    |
+---+------+--------+
```

Comentarios:

- Te recomiendo usar `PATINDEX()` por sobre `CHARINDEX()` para buscar el patrón inicial, tiene algo más de flexibilidad y nos permite mayor precisión a la hora de encontrar un patrón. Por ejemplo: `PATINDEX('% Año [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', PARRAFO)` esto buscará `Año` seguido de 4 números, no fallará si se encuentra el texto `Año del nacimiento del General San Martín`, mientras que `CHARINDEX()` si lo hará
- El `Año` no necesita dos patrones distintos siempre que la tabla este configurada como no sensible a minúsculas/mayúsculas.
- Para el `Número` si, puedes observar que usamos el `CASE WHEN` para determinar según un patrón, el comportamiento del recorte. Importantisimo, siempre que uses este tipo de estructura, es fundamental que los patrones más específicos estén primeros y los más generales al final.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu información. me ha servido !